# show/hide alertbox with data-attribute in twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

I want to show hide alert box in **twitter bootstrap using data attributes**, it is because so that i can use multiple alert boxes in one page...

Currently i have this,

```
<a href="#" data-box="myAlert">Hint</a> //data-box is the id of the box

<div id="myAlert" class="alert alert-info">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
    <p>Alert Me !!!!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working for you?

Comment: i dnt have the jquery for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){

  $('[data-box]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#' + $this.data('box')).show()
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.alert .close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.alert').hide()
  });

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDglZl?p=preview)

**Update**
Use the anchor tab to show/hide

```
<a href="#" data-box="myAlert">Hint</div>

<div id="myAlert" class="alert alert-info hide">
    <p>Alert Me !!!!</p>
</div>  

$(function(){

  $('[data-box]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#' + $this.data('box')).toggle()
    return false;
  });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/8zS3pi?p=preview)

Comment: It is because of are using the `close` button provided by bootstrap, it removes the alert box on click

Comment: @SaurabhLP if you want it to hide again when the link it clicked change .show() in the above code to .toggle()

Comment: @SaurabhLP write your own close method, which just hides the alert instead of removing it

Comment: @ArunPJohny what if i remove the close button and make "Hint" anchor for show/hide...

Comment: @SaurabhLP that will be better